# Licking your fingers after eating is called what?

Tags: verbs

I can't find it. What is licking your fingers after eating is called?

I'm not asking if it's rude/social acceptable, I'm asking what the action is called?

I'm not asking if it's called cleaning, there's a name for specifically licking your food stained fingers, I can't remember what it was.

Comment: I just call it “licking your fingers.”

Comment: Agree with @godel9: It's just called "licking your fingers after eating." And if you somehow manage to find some Latinate confection that actually means that, I'd avoid it because the odds are extremely unlikely that anyone else will actually know what it means.

Comment: related [The action of getting bite-sized pieces of bread](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/16049/the-action-of-getting-bite-sized-pieces-of-bread/16052#16052)

Answer (score 1):

Said about something being so delicious as to make you want to even lick your fingers that touched what you have eaten is [finger-licking good](https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=Finger%20Licking%20Good). The equivalent adjectives might be [toothsome](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/toothsome), 
[mouthwatering](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/mouthwatering), [lip-smacking](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/lip-smacking).

Answer (score 0):

It is simply called

> **finger lickin'**

Kentucky Fried Chicken uses the phrase in their ad campaigns: [Finger Lickin' Good](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finger_lickin%27_good)

Comment: I wouldn't say it's *called* "finger lickin'", though.  That's just eye dialect for the exact same phrase, really.